# NullPointerException string to int

Tags: android, string, nullpointerexception, int

I am trying to write a programm that will get the number input in the EditText field and convert it to integer so that I could use it later to set a timer for the app.  I want to make it that if one of 2 buttons is clicked, the EditText will be checked. If nothing is typed in there, I want a message to pop up asking to input the number of seconds for the timer. If there is a number, I want the programm to start a new activity. This is the code I have:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Start extends Activity  {
    Button button1;
    EditText et;
    String timer;
    int timer1;
    Button button2;
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start);
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);


        button2.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (timer.isEmpty()){
                    AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder (Start.this);
                    build.setMessage("Please, type in the number of seconds");
                    build.setNegativeButton("Okay,Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            finish();   
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = build.create(); 
                    alert.show();

                }
                else{ 
                    bull();

                Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(startMain);
                timer = et.getText().toString();
                bull();
                int secondsDelayed = 1;
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Start.this, MainActivity.class);

                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                }, secondsDelayed * timer1*1000);
            }

        }
        });

        button1.setOnClickListener ( new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (timer.isEmpty()){
            AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder (Start.this);
            build.setMessage("Please, type in the number of seconds");
            build.setNegativeButton("Okay,Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    finish();   
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = build.create(); 
            alert.show();

        }
        else{ 
            bull();

        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);
        bull();
        int secondsDelayed = 1;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Start.this, MainActivity2.class);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
        }, secondsDelayed * timer1*1000);
    }
    }
});

    }

    private void bull() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        timer1 = Integer.parseInt(timer);

    }



}
```

However, I get NullPointerException. Where is my mistake? Thanks

Here's my LogCat:

```
03-18 22:16:57.506: I/Process(3008): Sending signal. PID: 3008 SIG: 9
03-18 22:17:19.948: D/skia(3858): new locale en-Latn-GB
03-18 22:17:19.998: D/dalvikvm(3858): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 80K, 7% free 17272K/18412K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
03-18 22:17:20.008: I/dalvikvm-heap(3858): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.149MB for 2359312-byte allocation
03-18 22:17:20.018: D/dalvikvm(3858): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 6% free 19574K/20720K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
03-18 22:17:20.038: D/dalvikvm(3858): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 19574K/20720K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 18ms
03-18 22:17:20.148: D/libEGL(3858): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
03-18 22:17:20.148: D/libEGL(3858): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
03-18 22:17:20.148: D/libEGL(3858): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
03-18 22:17:20.148: I/Adreno200-EGL(3858): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3579225)
03-18 22:17:20.148: I/Adreno200-EGL(3858): Build Date: 04/22/13 Mon
03-18 22:17:20.148: I/Adreno200-EGL(3858): Local Branch: adreno_sba_20130419
03-18 22:17:20.148: I/Adreno200-EGL(3858): Remote Branch: 
03-18 22:17:20.148: I/Adreno200-EGL(3858): Local Patches: 
03-18 22:17:20.148: I/Adreno200-EGL(3858): Reconstruct Branch: 
03-18 22:17:20.208: D/OpenGLRenderer(3858): Enabling debug mode 0
03-18 22:17:28.096: D/GestureDetector(3858): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 11 mFalseSizeCnt:0
03-18 22:17:29.167: D/GestureDetector(3858): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 4 mFalseSizeCnt:0
03-18 22:17:29.187: D/AndroidRuntime(3858): Shutting down VM
03-18 22:17:29.187: W/dalvikvm(3858): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4104fac8)
03-18 22:17:29.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3858): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 22:17:29.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3858): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 22:17:29.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3858):     at com.example.scaryme.Start$2.onClick(Start.java:78)
03-18 22:17:29.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3858):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4354)
03-18 22:17:29.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3858):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17962)
03-18 22:17:29.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3858):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-18 22:17:29.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3858):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-18 22:17:29.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3858):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-18 22:17:29.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3858):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
03-18 22:17:29.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3858):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 22:17:29.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3858):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-18 22:17:29.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3858):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
03-18 22:17:29.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3858):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
03-18 22:17:29.187: E/AndroidRuntime(3858):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is line 78 `Start.java`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue seems to be that you never initialized timer. So calling timer.isEmpty() in your on click method is failing since timer is null.  You should be able to fix this by just giving timer a default value of "".

Comment: `timer = et.getText().toString();`

Comment: That isn't called until after timer.isEmpty() though.

Comment: could be but this is a guess.

Comment: Line 78 of that file is ' if (timer.isEmpty()){ ' Pretty sure that would be the issue.

Comment: hmm but op hasn't mentioned line 78. i could have answered before you but i was waiting for more info. In any case you guess could be right

Comment: @JacobMalliet, Thanks. That was the problem. No it works fine!